# VSCode merge conflict options not displaying

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on an application in which I have merged my code to the repository after taking the git pull.The problem is that earlier it was showing the options like **accept current change** , **accept incoming change**, **accept both the changes**. But now it is not showing the options now , I have taken the **pull** and **stash poped** my code but no I am stuck as I cannot proceed further.

**Below are the snapshots for better understanding**

[image: It is showing the options now]

[image: Not showing anywhere]

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241098/accept-incoming-change-not-appearing-in-vs-code/47248481" or "https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627902/10805479"

Comment: Ravi Ashara : it is not working fully. Any other possible solution

Comment: your "Code Lens" is enable?? or close vs code and open again

Comment: Ravi Ashara : Yes Code lens is enables

Comment: I am also having the same issue, checked in the link above but nothing works, tried delete and reinstall, but still no luck

Answer (score 88):

If you still struggle with this issue try to turn off Git: Merge Editor flag.
[image: settings]

Comment: Thank you! you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Thanks! It saved my day, but I still wonder why it happens. Is there a PR to VSCode for this?

Comment: Thanks, It just saved a lot of time  @nata

Comment: This worked, don't know if it has anything to do with latest update of VScode

Comment: The behavior came with the [July 2022 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_3way-merge-editor-improvements) which enabled a new 3-way merge editor by default. This solution was also proposed in [a GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158674#issuecomment-1222418061).

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE [August 2022 (VSCode version 1.71)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_merge-editor-improvements): Looks like the VSCode team heard our cries, and the experience has been improved:

> The old inline conflict decorators are no longer disabled, so the merge editor and inline experience can be used together.

> A file that has a conflict will now automatically show an Open in Merge Editor button to transition between the text and merge editors.

---

The behavior came with the [July 2022 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_3way-merge-editor-improvements) which enabled a new 3-way merge editor by default.

To use the new 3-way merge editor, see [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626228).

[image: New VSCode 3-way merge editor enabled by default in the July 2022 update]

Comment: The update expects a change of developer behaviour: Now when you want to resolve a conflict you have to go to the Source Control view and do it through there. Whereas before it was assumed that you wanted to do that when viewing a file in Explorer. Not a good change for me.

Comment: @powlo see edit – the experience was improved in the August 2022 update.

Answer (score 1):

## **Merge the branch to activate vscode merge editor**

here are the steps:
what you have to do is go to the console/terminal a manually merge the branch that has the conflict into yours. So lets say for example that i was working on branch **feat/#123/catalog** and i wanted to merge into branch **main** or **master** or whatever branch you want your pull request for.

1. go to console/terminal
2. make sure you are on the branch with the changes then type `git merge main` and hit enter.
3. you will get a message that says `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`
4. open vscode and click on the merge conflict files to use the merge editor

good luck