# Visual Studio Code: Review Merge Changes Side by Side, rather than top down

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-git

Is there any way to compare file changes in Visual Studio Code Side By Side,  rather than top down? Regular Visual Studio Enterprise has this option.

This is during git merge conflict resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

2022: update for [VSCode 1.69 (June 2022)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#3-way-merge-editor), as noted in [Audwin Oyong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10158227/audwin-oyong)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72995431/6309), there is now a 3-way merge view, which allows a side-by-side resolution.

> In this release, we continued working on the 3-way merge editor.
> This feature can be enabled by setting `git.mergeEditor` to `true` and will be enabled by default in future releases.
>
> The merge editor allows you to quickly resolve Git merge conflicts. >
> When enabled, the merge editor can be opened by clicking on a conflicting file in the Source Control view.
> Checkboxes are available to accept and combine changes in `Theirs` or `Yours`:
>
> [image: Merge Editor Conflict Resolution Demo]

And VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) will offer a way to open the regular file (not in 3 way merge mode).
Same as diff editor, it could use an action in the editor title area

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1926584/176448981-01a0b0e4-5261-4ec3-9e27-1efb68c6b39a.png]

See [PR 155159](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/155159) and its new action `merge.openResult`.

[Audwin Oyong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10158227/audwin-oyong) adds, based on the [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/913c6d1faa66cbcfed6fd23c120745894e289f96/release-notes/v1_69.md#3-way-merge-editor):

> To turn off the 3-way merge view, you can set `git.mergeEditor` to `false`.

Open the VSCode settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>:

[image: git.mergeEditor setting]

<sup>(From [Harshil Patanvadiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9370716/harshil-patanvadiya)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73556238/6309))</sup>

---

2021: By default, you see all conflicts "top down", but for each one, clicking on "compare changes" would open a tab with a side-by-side diff.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1926584/26586117/7e70828a-454e-11e7-9bb6-67646a20bfe0.gif]

(from [issue 27562](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27562))

Not ideal, but a good workaround.

---

In VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022):

> ### [Merge Editor: Toggling word wrap should apply to all editors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155280)
>
> It was weird when I toggled word wrap in the merge editor yet only the editor I was focused on had it toggled.
> I kind of expected all editors to have it toggled.
>
> My rationale is that toggling word wrap is usually a symptom of having long lines and the chances that all three editors have long lines is high if a single editor has long lines.

And:

> ### [Improve Merge Editor Story For Files Having/Getting Conflict Markers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153800#issuecomment-1219762873)
>
> Originally we had this icon along to toggle between the raw file and merge editor views. Could use it with this new label too.
> git-merge felt out of place as an icon choice to my eyes.
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25163139/185460190-0d652b9c-a4a7-4cb6-8958-80e42a72f0f7.png]

Comment: It sucks that you can't edit in the side by side view (the way Beyond Compare allows).

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb I agree. Maybe it will be possible in a future version of VSCode.

Comment: That mergeEditor is terrible...

Comment: @mr_squall It was just introduced in 1.69. Hopefully, it will improve over time.

Comment: How can I revert back to the old way of merging? This change makes it impossible for me to resolve conflicts, and VSCode was the absolute best way I had found for this.

Comment: @eirikvaa To turn off the 3-way merge view, you can set `git.mergeEditor` to `false`. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#3-way-merge-editor

Comment: @AudwinOyong Thank you. I have included that setting in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @AudwinOyong So it's either the 3-way merge or the highway? Too bad.

Comment: I'm so glad for this post, as my vscode updated and got forced to use the 3-way merge view and  imo its horrible compared to the inline feature

Comment: I have used VS Code to merge everything because of the inline feature.  With the new 3-way, I like the checkbox as the means of choosing what to merge. I'll give it a try, but I'm glad I know I can revert. Thanks for the post.

Comment: I can't stand this new 3 way approach. old one was much better. specially for hard conflicts.

Comment: i just saw this 3-way view few months ago and man IDK why everyone hate it, I LOVE IT! something that finally i can use on different platforms as a diff editor-vscode- and it actually make sense. maybe I saw the fixed version, maybe early versions were not be the best but, one I used was awesome. Today I was trying to enable the 3-way view and without the last picture you posted on the answer I couldn found it. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

This is a horrible update. to revert back, just add this `"git.mergeEditor": false` to settings.json .

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did mentioned that in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626228/6309).

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, but does answer [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67703214) which people seeing this may be asking.

Answer (score 8):

The three-ways to show the file it's so much difficult

Flow the below step to easy way to change the config view

1. Go to the vscode settings
2. Search the **`git.mergeEditor`**
3. **`Git:Merge Editor`** make it **`FALSE`**

[image: Git conflig view change]

Comment: I did mentioned  `git.mergeEditor` in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626228/6309) before, but this is a good summary. I used your picture in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

VSCode version 1.69 now includes Three-way merge (3-way merge).

See [release note 3-way merge](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#3-way-merg).

[image: demo of 3-way merge]

Comment: Good point, I missed that in my old answer. I have updated said answer, with a link back to yours.