# How to disable/turn off 3-way merge editor view in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

Until recently, in VSCode, handling merge conflicts was simple (to me, at least):

- Accept Current Change,
- Accept Incoming Change,
- Accept Both Changes,
- Compare Changes.

It used to be something like this:

[image: VSCode merge-conflict original view]

[source](https://linuxpip.org/fix-merge-conflicts-vscode/)

However, from `v1.70` onwards, it's been updated. See [v1.70 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_3way-merge-editor-improvements)

Now, it looks something like this:

[image: VSCode merge-conflict new view]

[source](https://dev.to/vscodetips/vs-code-tip-of-the-week-3-way-merge-editor-416h)

At this point, I don't like this new view. So, how can I turn it off and change it back to the original one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change VS Code's merge conflict layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73277690/how-to-change-vs-codes-merge-conflict-layout)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As I understand, you need to disable **git.mergeEditor** in your user settings:

https://dev.to/vscodetips/vs-code-tip-of-the-week-3-way-merge-editor-416h

Answer (score 23):

Inspired from [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19752290/andrew)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73337596/) and the [link](https://dev.to/vscodetips/vs-code-tip-of-the-week-3-way-merge-editor-416h) to my original question, either put this

```
"git.mergeEditor": false
```

in your `settings.json` file or

Open settings, and uncheck the following checkbox:

[image: Git:Merge Editor - checkbox]

After this, you may need to reload the window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, search for `Developer: Reload Window`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or restart the VSCode.

Comment: Thanks!! Btw it froze a bit like 5seconds but I do not need to reload the window.