Is it possible to split diff in vscode merge tool?
Frequently, when two unrelated changes occur in consecutive lines, the merge tool considers them as a single conflict. Is it possible to manually split the diff into two, and resolve them separately?

have you tried disabling multiDiffEditor.experimental.enabled? or git.mergeEditor? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/73277690/11107541)

That's not what I mean. I want to use the three-way merge editor. I'm asking if it provides option to manually split or merge diffs similar to what kdiff3 has.
