# Git showing text instead of option when conflict

Tags: javascript, git, git-merge-conflict

When I got conflict I have to manually delete the option, I don't know when and how it's happening.

[image: conflicts]

Can someone help me to bring back the option to solve the conflict?

Comment: You're meant to edit the file until it looks how you want then stage and commit it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed supposed to remove the conflict markers, keeping only the code sections you want for resolving the merge.

Note that is the screenshots represents a VSCode editor view, and if you are using VSCode 1.69 (June 2020) or more, there is a [**new merge view**, which allows a side-by-side resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626228/6309).

However, that means the old merge conflict decorators are no longer there.

Setting `git.mergeEditor` to `false` might help you to revert to the old behavior.