# Accept Incoming Change not appearing in VS Code (VS Code Version 1.61.2)

Tags: visual-studio-code, codelens

I have a problem, where I don't see the toolbar for merge conflicts in Visual Studio Code even after enabling the `editor.codeLens`.

[image: codeLens enabled]

[image: code example]

Any idea what else it can be?
I tried to restart VS Code, disabling/enabling editor.codeLens.
I even installed/uninstalled Gitlens - Git supercharged.

Thank you in advance.

Reference for my inputs are from:
[Accept Incoming Change not appearing in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241098/accept-incoming-change-not-appearing-in-vs-code/69808408#69808408)

Comment: Any Luck with this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Yes, I found a workaround. I installed a different extension for SSH. When I started using Remote - SSH (the one with 12.2m downloads) the toolbar suddenly appeared. Before I used SSH FS. Maybe you have an extension installed that has a problem with the toolbar like I had. @TahaMalik

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still can't solve this issue. You can turn off the `Git: Merge Editor` from `Setting` menu.

[image: merge editor option]

[VSCode merge conflict options not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703214/vscode-merge-conflict-options-not-displaying)

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the VSCode and reinstalled it but doens't work.
Then I completely uninstalled the VSCode along with its data, caches, temporary files And Reinstalled it and Worked like a charm.

Before that I tried enabling `CodeLens` and Adding VSCode as default merge tool, difftool and whatever is available on the internet, nothing worked.

Basically what I deduce is, there is some extension that have malfunctioned your VSCode git merge tool or its settings. You can try uninstalling all extensions first before completly uninstall the VSCode

### Uninstall Completely

---

**For Mac** run following command in terminal[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561948/8647537)

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist 
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist 
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/
rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/
rm -fr ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/
rm -fr ~/.vscode/
```

**For Windows** [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689843/8647537)

```
Go to Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
Double Click uninstall.exe
This will uninstall VS Code from Your Windows OS and
After uninstallation delete code folder also.
Open Run (Win + R) and Enter %appdata% Press Enter
Delete the folder code
```

Delete this folder as well `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689802/8647537)