# Visual code git features not working out of sudden

Tags: visual-studio-code

Out of sudden I noticed the git options not working in my visual code editor. All I see are the plain text, they used to be segment in different background color and also links where I can click to accept incoming/remain current changes etc..

**Current problem is showing this**
[image]

**Should be like this**
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by git options?

Comment: hi, I have updated my question with reference. Im not exactly sure what are they called, Im referring to the "Accept Current Change | Accept Incoming Change | ..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accept Incoming Change not appearing in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241098/accept-incoming-change-not-appearing-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

In VS code there is another way to merge code conflicts which you can find

```
Settings -> Git Merge (under user tab).
```

just uncheck that and then it will show you Merge options on your page like you are looking for.

[image: VS Code Settings]

Hope this helps.