# Visual Studio Code Merge Conflict UI not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a merge conflict with VS Code that I'm trying to resolve. My current screen doesn't seem to show options for 'accepting current change', 'accepting incoming change' etc.

[image]

I'm expecting the UI to be like this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241098/accept-incoming-change-not-appearing-in-vs-code ?

Answer (score 0):

MANUAL FIX:

I remember you , vs code is a text editor , so you can take and delete , change everything you see even when you see UI for merge .

At this point pay attention to what you choose and delete the rest,  or if you both need to copy what you find inside the head below and then delete the head, then continue with git , commit , pull , push and you should resolve the merge  .

I remind you to delete the comments ( I’ll leave you some notes on the merge comments ), which will otherwise cause problems in the code  :

```
<<<<<<<< < Head : indicates the code in head already present in the repository
========== : indicates the beginning of the one with which you would replace the head 
>>>>>>>>fd6.... : indicates the end of what to replace the head with
```

Comment: I know how to resolve the conflicts manually. My question is why doesn't the automatic UI show up. Did I toggle a setting?